# lilypond: giving no space to an invisible (grace) note in a music function

Tags: scheme, lilypond

I want to automate the process of adding falling gliss lines to notes and chords for slides on a guitar, just as found in the snippets documentation [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/snippets/fretted-strings#fretted-strings-slides-in-tablature) (see the one marked with `\afterGrace`).

As it is there, it retains the space for the invisible grace note, but it doesn't need to be there. The following is the function I've come up with so far:

```
fall = #(define-music-function (inputA) (ly:music?)
    (define gliss (ly:music-deep-copy inputA))
    (define grace (ly:music-deep-copy inputA))
        (set! (ly:music-property gliss 'articulations)
          (cons (make-music (quote GlissandoEvent))
                (ly:music-property gliss 'articulations)))
    #{
        \afterGrace $gliss
        \transpose c g, {
            \once \omit Stem
            \once \omit Flag
            \once \omit Accidental
            \once \hideNotes
            $grace
        }
    #})
```

I add the gliss manually with scheme because it doesn't work if `\glissando` is appended to the variable.

How can I remove the space caused by the invisible grace?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find  a solution, although it feels somewhat hacky:

```
    #{
        \afterGrace 16/16
        ...
```

First, I added `16/16`, which moves the grace note as far right as possible.

```
        \transpose c g, {
            ...
            \once \override NoteHead.font-size = #-50
            $grace
        }
    #})
```

Then, I overrode the font size of the note head to an infinitesimal value, which made it disappear